# Using hover through Particles.js

Tags: javascript, css, web, hover, particles

js and provided a heading inside the Particle-js div. But now I can't use heading1:hover. I already tried

```
#particles-js {pointer-events : none;}
```

But it did not work.

Link to my website (you can use inspect): http://freshdesignz.000webhostapp.com/

Comment: Please read: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428)

Comment: I know it isnt helpfull to just post a link, but I cant put the code in jsfiddle, because I cant reproduce the Problem and so it wont be helpfull. I already described my Problem and thats all I can do in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that particle-js overlaps the h1 tag. A possible solution would be to set the z-index for your h1 to a value > 0.

The problem you'll face than is that the mouse pointer only triggers the hover of your h1 and not the particle effect if you focus on the h1 element. You can reduce the with of the h1 to improve the ux

Comment: It worked in my short test in chrom dev tools. Just to clarify: You want to use mouseover on your h1 tag? Therefore the element must be above the partial-js canvas

Comment: Yeah but just adjusting the z-index work for my case? Or do I need to find a way to have my H1 outside of the Particle-div?

Comment: [this](https://prnt.sc/gjnmi7) worked for me :) It would also work, if you position the h1 after the particle-js element and do a absolute position middle/center on that element.